# Laravel Multi-role unable to create in laravel 5

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, roles

I am having trouble creating multi-role application in laravel5 since in laravel 5 the authentication is pre defined so I am not willing to mess around with predefined codes of laravel 5 authentication. I have a constructor that authenticates every controller in my project but I am unable to check user roles for the following roles:-

```
 1. Admin
 2. Agent
 3. User
```

I can check manually for every functions but that is not the right process of doing so and if I have a total of around 500 functions I cant go in every function and define manually. please any help

Thank you

Comment: You didn't give a clear understanding of what you are doing, are there 20 roles for 500 routes or what? But may be what you are looking for is using Route Filters to help organize it, take a look at Zizaco:entrust even if you don't use the service may be the examples will help you develope a route filter or other answer suitable for your project.

Comment: There are three roles of different users. roles are mentioned above in the question. I just want to create three level of authentication for different users->roles.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use middleware and route groups to accomplish the task, which would be similar the way Laravel checks for user authentication.

You just have to determine when you need to run the middleware, which can be done by nesting `Route::group`'s or injecting the middleware from your controller.

So, for an example of nesting you can have something like this in your routes file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

  Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard', function () {
      return view('dashboard');
  }]);    


  Route::group(['prefix' => 'company', 'namespace' => 'Company', 'middleware' => ['App\Http\Middleware\HasRole'], function () {

      Route::get('dashboard', ['as'=>'dashboard', function () {
          return view('company.dashboard');
      }]);
      Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeesController');
      ...
      ...
  });

});
```

or you can inject the middleware to your controllers like so:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class AwesomeController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('hasRole', ['only' => 'update'])
    }

}
```

And then add a one or more Middleware files using something like `php artisan make:middleware HasRole` which will give you the middleware boiler plate which you could then add your role checking logic:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HasRole {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
     if($request->is('admin/*')){

        [******ADD YOUR LOGIC HERE TO DETERMINE THE ROLE ******]
        [******YOU CAN ALSO INCLUDE ANY REDIRECTS IF NECESSARY******]

      }         
     return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Notice I used the `$route->is('admin/*')` to filter any routes as an example of further filtering requests, which you would probably not include if you are injecting the middleware from the controller.

But if the user passes the required role check you do not need to do anything and they will be allowed to continue to the view. If they fail the role check, you can handle that accordingly, but beware of getting them caught in a failed permission loop.

I assume you get the gist of it, feel free to look into the [Laravel middleware docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware) for more info.